# Subdomain request defaulting to main domain index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My question is related to this question [Index files for Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980232/index-files-for-subdomains) but it is an old question and there was no accepted answer.

I have a hosted site with sub-domains.  One sub domain works fine, but it has a .htaccess file that redirects everything to an index.php.

For the other sub-domain I don't want to do this.  It will link to specific pages, but for the homepage if I type in subdomain.domain.com/index it finds the page but if I type in subdomain.domain.com it reverts to the main domain index page i.e. www.domain.com/index  (rather than www.domain.com/subdomain/index).

I have the following in the main domain .htaccess but the conditions should stop this rewrite causing the problem right? (I have also commented all these out and still get the problem)

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$     [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1\.domain\.com$    [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub2\.domain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$       http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I also have

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

specified in the main domain .htaccess and subdomain .htaccess.

It feels like this should be something straight forward, can any body help?

Comment: How is your subdomain setup? Can you show its `VirtualHost` entry?

Comment: It was set up via the host control panel, it is registered as `sub2.domain.com` and refers to `www/sub2` in the file system (is that what you mean - I'm not using actual names).  I assume a redirect occurs somewhere for this, if I refer to files by name they are found - its only when left blank it finds the wrong index file.  I have also tried putting a specific redirect in my .htaccess file, but even that didn't work.